# Prevent database table row from delete and update

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table that want to protect some rows from deleting and updating. I am using MySQL database. How can fix it in phpmyadmin or sql syntax?

**EX:** prevent row with `id:18` from delete and update:

[image]

Comment: I use of this sql: `CREATE TABLE preserve_permissions (
  permission_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FOREIGN KEY (permission_id) REFERENCES permissions (permission_id)
);

INSERT INTO perserve_permissions (permission_id) VALUES (1234);` but i have error: Error
`SQL query:

CREATE TABLE preserve_permissions(

permission_id INT PRIMARY KEY ,
FOREIGN KEY ( permission_id ) REFERENCES permissions( permission_id )
);

MySQL said: 

#1005 - Can't create table 'mymy.preserve_permissions' (errno: 150) (Details...) `

Comment: You will have to adapt the code in that question to suit your specific needs and situation.  It should be used as a template and not copied verbatim.  The KEY and FOREIGN KEY need to be of the same data type.  I do believe that is the source of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various options.

**SESSION WISE: if you are using INNODB**

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
UPDATE table SET mainpage =1 WHERE id = 18;
-- do NOT commit until you want to release the lock.
-- if you do that under myisam, 
-- I think it is going to lock the whole table (to be verified)
```

**STRUCTURAL PROTECTION**

Create a trigger before update/delete on your table and raise an error when `:new.id = 18`

Comment: I copy above code in "Run SQL query/queries on database mymy:" and get error: `Error
SQL query:

UPDATE TABLE SET mainpage =1 WHERE id =18;


MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table SET mainpage =1 WHERE id = 18' at line 1 `

Comment: Are you telling me you didn't change the table name?

Comment: Well, I was wrong. I run it in box sql on phpmyadmin and get in same box as: `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). What is the purpose of trigger?

UPDATE access_level SET mainpage =1 WHERE id = 18;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).` What is the purpose of trigger?

Comment: Please explain more clearly?

Comment: The trigger is an optional option. This would be to ensure that if somebody modifies the row you want, there would be an error and the modification/deletion would fail.

Comment: @Sebas Given that you can only trigger after delete, this wouldn't prevent deletion.